# SharePoint Validation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, validation-list-items

I have a SharePoint site already created. I have noticed that members that are using my site will add their name to the "Name" Column, but they will not use the next Column "Decision" in some instances. Which is a not standard procedure.

So I would like to creat a validation that says, If you put your name in the name column, you HAVE to make a decision.

How would I right that formula in the valiation section of SP?

Comment: if you make it mandatory field, will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just a Name and Decision field, I'd suggest making both Name and Decision mandatory fields. You can do this by going to Library Settings > [Your Column] > Toggle the radio button to "Make field mandatory" > Save. This'll make it required to have all the "Mandatory" fields required to be filled out.

If there's a use case for your list where you wouldn't need both Name and Decision then you may want to use validation like the following. I suspect, but don't know for certain, that SharePoint Validation will work without inverting ISBLANK but you could try it as it simplifies things a lot more. I'll put both here just for reference. I'd advise trying the second one first, as if it works, it's easier for someone else to read later on...

With NOT-ISBLANK:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Name])),NOT(ISBLANK([Decision])),True)
```

Without NOT-ISBLANK:

```
=IF( [Name], [Decision], True )
```

This is the reference I like to use with SharePoint validations: [Link to Documentation](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html)

Here's the more "official" documentation: [office.com Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: @TravisHorne No problem! If this did help, please mark my answer as correct so future users know what worked for you. Thanks!